# Console output suppressed. Why?

Tags: bash

In my bash script I have a function that:

- contains an `expect` script spawning an SSH connection to a remote device
- and depending on whether the connection timed-out or not `echo`'s back a string to that effect (as a return value)

When I run the script from the terminal and the bash script reaches the statement of:

```
myExpectFunc
[further code...]
```

why is it that I can see the console output of the `expect` script, but if I do the following:

```
retVal=$(myExpectFunc)
[further code...]
```

there will be no console output? It is like it is suppressed until `retVal` has been assigned a value.

I'd like to keep `local` variables to functions and return the values of these variables as my return value for me to be able to `case` on. Of course if I don't declare `local` variables to the function the variable will be global and I can simply `case` on the global variable. But I'd rather not do this. So is there a way to be able to maintain the console output and assign the return value to `retval`?

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way to be able to maintain the console output and assign the return value to retval?

Yes.  Use `tee`:

```
retVal=$(myExpectFunc | tee /dev/tty)
```

All of the standard output from `myExpectFunc` is sent to the standard input of `tee`.  `tee` copies that to both to the file `/dev/tty` (which is your terminal) and to its own standard out (which is then captured by `retVal`).